# Cosa significa "stammi bene" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *L’amore ai tempi del Covid-19*<sup>1</sup>, di Antonio Manzini,  ho letto questo dialogo tra il vicequestore Rocco Schiavone e Fumagalli, un altro poliziotto, mentre stanno svolgendo un'indagine in un appartamento (grassetto mio):

> «Quanta gente abita qui dentro?» chiese Fumagalli. 
>       «Sono in sette, mi pare». 
>       «E io che mi lamento di stare da solo in 70 metri quadrati!».
>        «Non sei sempre da solo» fece Rocco, «la Gambino a casa tua non viene mai?». 
>       «No carino, vado io nella sua. 180 metri sul portico romano!» e gli fece l’occhiolino. 
>       «Sei un uomo squallido e profittatore... **stammi bene**».

Finito questo dialogo, i due continuano a lavorare nell'appartamento. Infatti, il testo continua così:

> Mentre Fumagalli infilava un paio di guanti di plastica, Rocco tornò in corridoio. «Antonio!» chiamò. Quello si affacciò sull’uscio. «Inutile dire che nessuno può uscire. E non devono usare il bagno».

Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bene1) ho trovato parecchi possibili significati della locuzione "stare bene". Non mi pare, però, che nessuno sia adatto al contesto di questo dialogo. Sapreste spiegarmi qual è il senso di questo "stammi bene" che appare nel brano sopra citato?

---

<sup>1. Secondo il [blog di Licia Corbolante](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2020/02/12/nome-malattia-coronavirus-2019-ncov/), che si occupa di ricerca terminologica e qualità linguistica, 
dovrebbe essere "della COVID-19", ma in questo racconto l'autore fa confusione tra virus e malattia.</sup>

Comment: È una formula di augurio, equivalente all'inglese "take care"; letteralmente "stai bene a me", ovvero "fallo per me (di stare bene)" - è quello che credo si chiami "dativo etico" che serve a rafforzare l'augurio. (cfr. http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mi1/). Non so se nel brano citato viene utilizzato in modo sarcastico.

Comment: Son d’accordo con @RiccardoDeContardi, si tratta di una forma colloquiale di saluto tra amici o conoscenti. Nel brano e probabilmente usata come intercalare.

Comment: Comunque è secondo me corretta la risposta che una forma di saluto per congedarsi

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi - sul discorso regionale non sono molto d’accordo . Penso sia usata o quantomeno capita in tutta Italia. Forse più usata al nord che al sud.

Comment: Nel contesto è usato in modo sarcastico: sarebbe un saluto amichevole, ma qui viene adoperato come congedo secco e distaccato. Ma l'intera frase va poi presa alla rovescia, perché i due sono amici.

Comment: La penso in modo molto simile a @egreg. È una specie di doppio sarcasmo: letteralmente “stammi bene” è ovviamente una raccomandazione positiva; qui potrebbe essere quasi tradotto in un “crepa” rivolto all'interlocutore definito scherzosamente, iperbolicamente “squallido e profittatore”; ma appunto è un “crepa” così come si potrebbe dare del figlio di buona donna a un amico. (D'altro canto non ho mai letto niente di Manzini: forse sarebbe d'aiuto saperne di più sui suoi personaggi in generale.)

Comment: @DaG: Personalmente è la prima volta che leggo Manzini (e, a dire il vero, questo racconto l'ho letto perché era un'opportunità di parlarne – in italiano – con altre persone grazie a un'iniziativa della rete di biblioteche pubbliche), ma su [questo articolo di Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocco_Schiavone) si trova un po' d'informazione sui personaggi.

Answer (score 1):

In generale, *stammi bene* è una formula di congedo che vuol significare *sta’ bene, ho a cuore la tua salute*.

Quindi non solo augurale come sarebbe il latino *Vale*: ha anche un pizzico di affetto.

Tuttavia, può essere adoperato anche in senso ironico. Per esempio, dopo una discussione accesa uno dei due interlocutori potrebbe congedarsi con *stammi bene*, intendendo: “non hai capito nulla di ciò che volevo dire, resta pure della tua idea”.

E sarebbe proprio questo caso! “Sei un uomo squallido e profittatore…”, con l'aggiunta di “stammi bene” nel senso “non voglio avere nulla a che fare con te”.

Naturalmente, però, qui il senso va preso alla rovescia e si capisce dall'occhiolino: i due sono amici, oltre che colleghi e l'ultima frase vuole essere solo una presa in giro, con anche un po’ di invidia verso il collega, probabilmente.

Comment: Come OP, il voto negativo mi causa perplessità. Qual è il problema in questa risposta? Per favore, potresti [fare lo sforzo di chiarirlo](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1337/)?